# How do I unpack a list with a varying amount of items into individual variables?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, streamlit, iterable-unpacking

```
import streamlit as st

sidebar_counter = 9
# this number can vary depending on what is selected by the user

column_list = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5]
# column_list can vary and be a list that is [col1, col5] and just two items depending on what is selected by the user

#my goal is to assign each col# to each column as follows:
col1, col2, col3, col4 = st.columns(sidebar_counter)

# where sidebar_counter will already include the number of columns selected.
```

is there any way to dynamically unpack the col1, col2, col3 depending on what is selected?

I have tried the following:

```
import streamlit as st

column_list = st.columns(sidebar_counter)
```

However, this does not work as when I call any columns (col1 for example), it is not defined.

Comment: If you don't know what variables you are defining, then how will you use them later anyway? If you don't know how many of something there will be, then using individual variables makes no sense. You can only treat what you have as a list, and loop over it.

Comment: If you have an idea in mind for how you'll use these variably-defined variables, you should include some example code for that in your question-- I suspect that once you start trying to write that example, what deceze said above will make more sense.  The good news is that you don't *need* to unpack a list to do things with it.  Lists are really useful all on their own.

Comment: The way I'll use these defined variables is in the second last bit of code:

#my goal is to assign each col# to each column as follows:
col1, col2, col3, col4 = st.columns(sidebar_counter)

Comment: No, the point is: what will you do with them *after* you have (hypothetically) successfully assigned them!?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
import streamlit as st

sidebar_counter = 9
column_list = st.columns(sidebar_counter)

for i in range(sidebar_counter):
    with column_list[i]:
        st.write(f'column {i+1}')
        # other stuffs ...
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can set the variable in the global dictionary, and then you can call the variable in your script. For example:

```py
for s in range(sidebar_counter):
    globals()[f"col{s+1}"] = column_list[s]
```

Alternatively, you can set the variable in the local dictionary and then call the variable into a function. For example:

```py
for s in range(sidebar_counter):
    locals()[f"col{s+1}"] = column_list[s]
```

However, in my opinion, the best approach is to save the variable in a regular dictionary, and then you can work with that dictionary.

Comment: Since the values are *already* in a list, even putting it in a dictionary is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @Samwise, I agreed

Comment: Hmmm I'm not familiar with the term "global dictionary" and may have to do some research on implementing this.

Comment: @WaqarQureshii is the dictionary where python save the globals variables. Probably in the documentation is called different.